# how to insert data with laravel and ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have this error:

http://localhost:8000/monthlyadd 500 (Internal Server Error)

error code:

```
message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'monthly_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `month_monthly` (`month_id`, `monthly_id`) values (1, ?))"
```

how to solve this error?

my controller code

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $monthly = new Monthly();
        $monthly->user_id = Auth::id();
        $monthly->result = $request->input('result');
        $monthly->problem = $request->input('problem');
        $monthly->suggestion = $request->input('suggestion');
        $monthly->months()->attach(request('month'));
        $monthly->years()->attach(request('year'));
        $monthly->save();
    }
```

js code:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#addform').on('submit', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "/monthlyadd",
                  data: $('#addform').serialize(),
                  success: function(response){
                      console.log(response)
                      $('#exampleModal').modal('hide')
                      alert ("data seved")
                  },
                  error: function(error){
                      console.log(error)
                      alert ("data not seve")
                  }
              });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

route:

```
Route::post('/monthlyadd', 'MonthlyController@store');
```

modal monthly

```
public function months()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Month::class);
    }
```

modal month:

```
  public function monthlies()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Monthly::class);
    }
```

Comment: in .env `APP_DEBUG=true` on debugger and see error in details and post that error

Comment: updated my error

Comment: `'monthly_id' cannot be null` this is your error you can fix easily i guess

Comment: what is the model for the table `month_monthly`

Comment: I have 3 tables 1-table month  2- table monthly  3- table month_montly and I joined table month and table monthly, table month_monthly don't need to modal

Answer (score 0):

your error is : monthly_id cannot be null
you can fix it by setting default value for it from your migration or phpmyadmin

or
in your store function set it to something:

```
$monthly->monthly_id= 'some-value';
```